# Play audio on Ubuntu Core!

Tags: sound, jack, ubuntu-core

I installed Ubuntu Core 14.04 AMD 64.
Now I want to play an audio! What exactly should be installed?!
(I got this message on webkitgtk: jack server is not running or cannot be started)

I got this by run "lshw -short" command:

```
H/W path      Device      Class       Description
=================================================
                          system      VirtualBox ()
/0                        bus         VirtualBox
/0/0                      memory      128KiB BIOS
/0/1                      memory      490MiB System memory
/0/2                      processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU       M 460  @ 2.53GHz
/0/100                    bridge      440FX - 82441FX PMC [Natoma]
/0/100/1                  bridge      82371SB PIIX3 ISA [Natoma/Triton II]
/0/100/1.1                storage     82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 IDE
/0/100/2                  display     VirtualBox Graphics Adapter
/0/100/3      eth0        network     82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller
/0/100/4                  generic     VirtualBox Guest Service
/0/100/5                  multimedia  82801AA AC'97 Audio Controller
/0/100/6                  bus         KeyLargo/Intrepid USB
/0/100/7                  bridge      82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ACPI
/0/100/b                  bus         82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller
/0/3          scsi0       storage     
/0/3/0.0.0    /dev/sda    disk        10GB VBOX HARDDISK
/0/3/0.0.0/1  /dev/sda1   volume      3812MiB EXT4 volume
/0/4          scsi1       storage     
/0/4/0.0.0    /dev/cdrom  disk        DVD reader
```

Comment: @EliahKagan Do we really *need* hardware information to tell him to install a sound server? The chances we will actually need that info is pretty low.

Comment: @Seth Somehow I got the impression more had already been (unsuccessfully) attempted than actually was. You're right--this can probably be answered perfectly, as-is. **MisamSaki:** Sorry about that--I was wrong to say we needed [that information](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) at this time.

Comment: @EliahKagan I put my hardware information in the question content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I solved it!

We need only the `alsa-base` and `gstreamer0.10-alsa` packages.

Comment: Please tell how you added these packages? alsa-base does not appear in the snappy lists ... ?

Comment: @GForty sudo apt-get install alsa-base gstreamer0.10-alsa

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you have some embedded board and intend to plug in some USB Audio Class device to have it play audio?

JACK is a sound server that can be installed with the `jackd` package, if you didn't know that already.

Note that JACK is intended for professionals. If you didn't use JACK before and just want to play audio similar to what is used in the Ubuntu Desktop releases you should have a look at the `alsa-base` and probably `pulseaudio` packages to get things started (be aware of the dependencies that are being pulled in!).

The error message requiring "jack server" may just be misleading, as most applications should work fine with PulseAudio or ALSA alone.

Comment: I know JACK and I don't need to jackd package. I want to play audio, only! I installed alsa-base and pulseaudio packages but my problem not resolved.

Comment: @MisamSaki Did you reboot the machine?

Comment: @Seth Yes! I did